# ASP.NET Core Identity - Multiple Login Types

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to use Identity as my login framework but I have a specific requirement that I need to facilitate and am not sure if it is possible. I need to be able to allow the user to login using multiple username types namely :

```
Email
Phone Number
Username
Third Party Token ( Facebook / Twitter / Other System provided keys through token pass through )
```

Furthermore I need to have a multiple authentication states namely :

```
Public (normal guest)
Detected (we know who you are but you have not yet provided a password)
Logged In (you have securely logged in)
```

To solve problem 1 I was considering using the `UserLogin` data and then setting up a `ProviderType` for each login type required.

So :

```
Login Provider = Email
`ProviderKey` = "someone@something.com"
Login Provider = Mobile
`ProviderKey` = "123456789"
```

These users would share the same password across the different login types (when required) so that should not be an issue, it's more of just being able to determine who they are (`FindByLoginAsync` custom store).

I have no Idea how I would go about configuring this so help there would be appreciated

Problem 2: I don't have a clue or even know if this is possible? Please help

Comment: Sounds like you want to add  the provider to AppUser,you may follow this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-custom-user-data-to-the-identity-db

Comment: For Detected (we know who you are but you have not yet provided a password)--you could check if user exists by FinbynameAsync and check the target column indicates if the user is detected

Comment: @RuikaiFeng - thanks for the feedback. Yes I have no problem "resolving" the user, but it was more of a question of how to store the "user state". I think I will just have to have some session flag that I can expose to the authentication system and allow it to check/update the state on certain actions

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed customize how identity handles login, by scaffolding identity and then getting in the code which you can modify to fit your needs. here is how you scaffold identity https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

to give you an overview, install "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" package and then scaffold identity in solution explorer. I recommend scaffolding everything at once, but what you are looking for is most likely the "SignInManager", as it manages the logins.

I dont exactly understand what you mean by "multiple authentication states" but if you want to add custom user data, you can do this by customizing identity, which will involve migration management and schema update using ef core. see "custom user data" section at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-user-data

Comment: I have indeed already done this, and even gone so far as to implement my own UserStore/RoleStore objects. The issue is that their interfaces only really expose `FindByUsername` overrides which does not fit my need for `FindByUsername(username,loginProvider)' type scenario.
The second part to my question is more around logged in states I.E you are either anonymous, or you came in with a cookie and did not enter a password (Detected), or you logged in with password (LoggedIn)

Comment: @MarkRedfern essentially you need to scaffold every identity razor page, and find out which exact method handles login, and write your own code in it. keep in mind you can always connect to database yourself and run your own LINQ queries instead of using `FindByUsername`, or even modify `FindByUsername` altogether if possible. I am not available at the moment to give you full code, but let me know if you figure it out. Otherwise I will try to give you some code later.